# How can I scrape data from SVG XLinks in <use> tags?

Tags: web-scraping, xlink

I'm trying to scrape some data from a webpage. One piece of text that I would like to grab is embedded with an SVG XLink in a 'use' tag. The href of the XLink is relative, seemingly linking to an id on the same page:

```
<use xlink:href="#18x18_info"></use>
```

I have searched for the corresponding id in the document, but cannot find it. How can I grab the data refered to by that xlink?

Please excuse me if I am using any terminology incorrectly, I am new to this and I am struggling to understand what is going on.

Comment: _“The href of the XLink is relative, seemingly linking to an id on the same page”_ - to be more specific, this likely refers to an element id inside another SVG image embedded into the page source. (Because that’s what you normally use `use` for.) _“How can I grab the data refered to by that xlink?”_ - not sure what exactly you want to “grab” in that situation …?

Comment: The data that I am trying to scrape is an address. In the page source, the address is not there - in its place, there is a <use> tag with an xlink pointing to the stated id.  I'm assuming that if I can find that id, then I can get the address. But I can't find the id. I would like to know either how to find the id, or how to otherwise scrape the address.

My appologies if I seem vague - like I say, my understanding of the problem is vague.

Comment: If you have something like `<use xlink:href="#foo"></use>`, then this must be referring to an id within the same document - most likely another svg element, that in turn contains a group/defs/path/whatever with that id. Call the page in your browser, and then use `document.getElementById(...)` via the console, that should show you what element this is referring to.

Comment: Good call using Javascript to find it. I had been using XPath and Firefox's Find on Page. I found the id. It doesn't look very much like an address, though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the sake of closure, I now have the address I needed. The xlink was to a little info symbol, not to the address. The address, for reasons I do not yet understand, was not in the set of nodes that I had extracted to scrape, which is why I wasn't finding it. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks again for your help - I have learned a few things from our interaction.